# lodash's without by property?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying use lodash's function `without` to exclude object from array by its property like this:

my array:

```
let arr = [
  {code: '001', data: 'foo data 1'}, 
  {code: '002', data: 'foo data 2'},
  {code: '003', data: 'foo data 3'},
  {code: '004', data: 'foo data 4'}]
```

function usage:

```
_.without(arr, {code: '002'})
```

I expected that function exclude item with code 002 from array but always give me all 4 items. Do I something wrong?. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Would `_.remove` or [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) be more appropriate? These forms accept predicates.

Comment: You can use `_.pick`/`_.omit` for this (`pick` is faster, but `omit` is easier to write).

Comment: @user2864740 thanks, filter should works

Comment: @SterlingArcher thanks for answer, but if I am not wrong functions which you mention are for object not array, it it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use _.reject:

```js
let arr = [
  {code: '001', data: 'foo data 1'}, 
  {code: '002', data: 'foo data 2'},
  {code: '003', data: 'foo data 3'},
  {code: '004', data: 'foo data 4'}]
  
  arr = _.reject(arr, {code: '002'});
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer!  You should still be able to use the matches iteratee shorthand like was used the in question. `_.reject(arr, { code: '002' })`

Comment: @DougCoburn Thanks! I updated the answer to reflect the shorthand as used in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`_.filter`**](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter):

```
let newArr = _.filter(arr, function(obj) {
    return obj.code !== "002";
});
```

shorter using an arrow function:

```
let newArr = _.filter(arr, obj => obj.code !== "002");
```

**Note:** If you want to alter the original array instead of creating a new one, then use [**`_.remove`**](https://lodash.com/docs/#remove) and change the test from `obj.code !== "002"` to `obj.code === "002"`.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has a "map" function that works just like jQuerys:

```js
let arr = [
  {code: '001', data: 'foo data 1'}, 
  {code: '002', data: 'foo data 2'},
  {code: '003', data: 'foo data 3'},
  {code: '004', data: 'foo data 4'}];

var data1 = _.map(arr, function(o) {
    if (o.code == "002") return o;
});

// Remove undefines from the array
data1 = _.without(data1, undefined)
```

or you can Use lodash _.filter method:

_`.filter(collection, [predicate=_.identity])`

Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

with predicate as custom function

`_.filter(arr, function(o) {`

`return o.code == '002';`

`});`

with predicate as part of filtered object (the _.matches iteratee shorthand)

`_.filter(arr, {code: '002'});`

with predicate as [key, value] array (the _.matchesProperty iteratee shorthand.)

`_.filter(arr, ['code', '002']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#reject) with a [`_.matches`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#matches) iteratee shorthand.

```js
const arr = [{"code":"001","data":"foo data 1"},{"code":"002","data":"foo data 2"},{"code":"003","data":"foo data 3"},{"code":"004","data":"foo data 4"}];
  
const result = _.reject(arr, {code: '002'});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```